# A portable parallel loop construct in C89

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

(There is a [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185709/a-portable-parallel-loop-construct-in-c89-follow-up) available.)

I was practicing writing some portable C89 code and came up with this parallel `for` loop construct. Basically, if you have a bunch of tasks that do not depend on each other, it makes sense to create a concurrent queue of those tasks, a pool of worker threads popping the queue and performing a task at a time:

**parallel_for.h**

```
#ifndef PARALLEL_FOR_H
#define PARALLEL_FOR_H

#include <stdlib.h>

#define ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS 0
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_ARGS 1
#define ERROR_FORP_UNKNOWN_CORES 2
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_INIT 3
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_DESTROY 4
#define ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL 5
#define ERROR_FORP_SSCANF_FAIL 6
#define ERROR_FORP_POPEN_FAIL 7
#define ERROR_FORP_CPU_FEOF 8
#define ERROR_FORP_CPU_FERROR 9
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_THREAD 10
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_SETCANCELTYPE 11
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_JOIN 12

/*******************************************************************************
* Runs a multithreaded for loop over the input array producing the results and *
* storing them in the output array.                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
int forp(void** input,
         void** output,
         size_t len,
         void* (*func)(void*));

/*************************************************************************
* Returns a human-readable description of an error code related to forp. *
*************************************************************************/
const char* forp_error(int error_code);

#endif /* PARALLEL_FOR_H */
```

**parallel_for.c**

```
#include "parallel_for.h"

#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <pthread.h>
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/********************************************
* This struct implements a queue node type. *
********************************************/
typedef struct concurrent_queue_node_t {
    void* queue_node_element;
    struct concurrent_queue_node_t* next_queue_node;
} concurrent_queue_node_t;

/******************************************************************************
* This struct implements a partially concurrent queue implemented as a linked *
* list.                                                                       *
******************************************************************************/
typedef struct concurrent_queue_t {

#if defined(__APPLE__)
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
#elif defined(__linux__)
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif

    size_t queue_size;
    concurrent_queue_node_t* queue_head_node;
    concurrent_queue_node_t* queue_tail_node;
} concurrent_queue_t;

/***********************************************
* Initializes a given queue to an empty state. *
***********************************************/
int concurrent_queue_t_init(concurrent_queue_t* queue)
{
#if defined(__APPLE__)
    int ret = pthread_mutex_init(&queue->mutex, NULL);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_INIT;
    }
#elif defined(__linux__)
    int ret = pthread_mutex_init(&queue->mutex, NULL);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_INIT;
    }
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    InitializeCriticalSection(&queue->criticalSection);
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif

    queue->queue_size = 0;
    queue->queue_head_node = NULL;
    queue->queue_tail_node = NULL;
    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
}

/***********************************************************************
* Appends a given element to the tail of the queue. This method is not *
* thread-safe since it is used by a single-threaded process.           *
***********************************************************************/
int concurrent_queue_t_enqueue(concurrent_queue_t* queue, void* element)
{
    concurrent_queue_node_t* queue_node = malloc(sizeof *queue_node);

    if (queue_node == NULL)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL;
    }

    queue_node->queue_node_element = element;
    queue_node->next_queue_node = NULL;

    if (queue->queue_size == 0)
    {
        queue->queue_head_node = queue_node;
        queue->queue_tail_node = queue_node;
    }
    else
    {
        queue->queue_tail_node->next_queue_node = queue_node;
        queue->queue_tail_node = queue_node;
    }

    queue->queue_size++;
    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
}

/*****************************************************************************
* Removes the head element of the queue. This method is thread-safe since it *
* is called from multiple distinct threads.                                  *
*****************************************************************************/
void* concurrent_queue_t_dequeue(concurrent_queue_t* queue)
{
    void* ret;
    concurrent_queue_node_t* head_node;

#if defined(__APPLE__)
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
#elif defined(__linux__)
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    EnterCriticalSection(&queue->criticalSection);
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif

    if (queue->queue_size == 0)
    {
        ret = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        head_node = queue->queue_head_node;
        ret = head_node->queue_node_element;
        queue->queue_head_node = queue->queue_head_node->next_queue_node;
        free(head_node);
        queue->queue_size--;
    }

#if defined(__APPLE__)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
#elif defined(__linux__)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    LeaveCriticalSection(&queue->criticalSection);
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif
    return ret;
}

/************************************************
* Releases all the resources held by the queue. *
************************************************/
int concurrent_queue_t_destroy(concurrent_queue_t* queue)
{
    while (concurrent_queue_t_dequeue(queue) != NULL) {}

#if defined(__APPLE__)
    int ret = pthread_mutex_destroy(&queue->mutex);
    return ret == 0 ? ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS : ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_DESTROY;
#elif defined(__linux__)
    int ret = pthread_mutex_destroy(&queue->mutex);
    return ret == 0 ? ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS : ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_DESTROY;
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    DeleteCriticalSection(&queue->criticalSection);
    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif
}

/******************************************************************************
* A task descriptor specifying the input element and the address at which the *
* output element should be stored.                                            *
******************************************************************************/
typedef struct task_descriptor {
    void* input_element;
    void** output_element_address;
} task_descriptor;

/**********************************************
* Returns the number of processors on Mac OS. *
**********************************************/
static int get_number_of_processors_apple(size_t* p_number_of_processors)
{
#ifdef __APPLE__
    FILE* fp;
    char output[10];
    int error_code;
    char* fgets_ret;

    fp = popen("sysctl -n hw.ncpu", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_POPEN_FAIL;
    }

    fgets_ret = fgets(output, 9, fp);

    if (fgets_ret != output)
    {
        if (feof(fp))
        {
            return ERROR_FORP_CPU_FEOF;
        }

        if (ferror(fp) != 0)
        {
            return ERROR_FORP_CPU_FERROR;
        }
    }

    error_code = sscanf(output, "%zu", p_number_of_processors);

    if (error_code == EOF)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_SSCANF_FAIL;
    }
#endif
    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
}

/*********************************************
* Returns the number of processors on Linux. *
*********************************************/
static int get_number_of_processors_linux(size_t* p_number_of_processors)
{
#ifdef __linux__
    *p_number_of_processors = (size_t)get_nprocs();
#endif
    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
}

/***********************************************
* Returns the number of processors on Windows. *
***********************************************/
static int get_number_of_processors_windows(size_t* p_number_of_processors)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    *p_number_of_processors = (size_t) 2 * si.dwNumberOfProcessors;
#endif
    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
}

/**************************************************************
* A portable function for returning the number of processors. *
**************************************************************/
static int get_number_of_processors(size_t* p_number_of_processors)
{
#if defined(__APPLE__)
    return get_number_of_processors_apple(p_number_of_processors);
#elif defined(__linux__)
    return get_number_of_processors_linux(p_number_of_processors);
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    return get_number_of_processors_windows(p_number_of_processors);
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif
}

/*****************************************************************************
* Specifies the worker thread arguments. Holds the queue and the function to *
* be applied to each queue element.                                          *
*****************************************************************************/
typedef struct worker_thread_proc_args {
    concurrent_queue_t* concurrent_queue;
    void* (*func)(void*);
    int return_status;
} worker_thread_proc_args;

/*********************************
* Implements the worker threads. *
*********************************/
void* worker_thread_proc(void* args)
{
    worker_thread_proc_args* worker_thread_proc_arguments =
    (worker_thread_proc_args*) args;

    int ret = 0;

#ifdef __APPLE__
    ret = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
#elif defined(__linux__)
    ret = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
#endif

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        worker_thread_proc_arguments->return_status = ret;
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        worker_thread_proc_arguments->return_status = 0;
    }

    concurrent_queue_t* concurrent_queue =
    worker_thread_proc_arguments->concurrent_queue;

    void* (*func)(void*) = worker_thread_proc_arguments->func;
    task_descriptor* task_desc;

    if (worker_thread_proc_arguments->return_status != 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    while ((task_desc = concurrent_queue_t_dequeue(concurrent_queue)) != NULL)
    {
        *task_desc->output_element_address = func(task_desc->input_element);
    }

    return NULL;
}

/***************************************
* Cancels all the first 'len' threads. *
***************************************/
#ifdef __APPLE__
void cancel_threads(pthread_t* pthreads, size_t len)
#elif defined(__linux__)
void cancel_threads(pthread_t* pthreads, size_t len)
#elif defined(_WIN32)
void cancel_threads(HANDLE* threads, size_t len)
#endif
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
#ifdef __APPLE__
        pthread_cancel(pthreads[i]);
#elif defined(__linux__)
        pthread_cancel(pthreads[i]);
#elif defined(_WIN32)
        TerminateThread(threads[i], 0);
#endif
    }
}

/***********************************************************
* The actual implementation of the parallel for construct. *
***********************************************************/
int forp(void** input, void** output, size_t len, void* (*func)(void*))
{
    size_t number_of_cores;
    size_t szi;
    int ret;
    int join_ret = ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
    concurrent_queue_t queue;
    task_descriptor* task_desc;
    worker_thread_proc_args* wtpa;

#ifdef __APPLE__
    pthread_t* threads;
#elif defined(__linux__)
    pthread_t* threads;
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    HANDLE* threads;
#endif

    if (input == NULL || output == NULL || func == NULL)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_NO_ARGS;
    }

    if (len == 0)
    {
        /*****************
        * Nothing to do. *
        *****************/
        return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
    }

    ret = get_number_of_processors(&number_of_cores);

    if (ret != ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    if (number_of_cores == 0)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_UNKNOWN_CORES;
    }

    if ((ret = concurrent_queue_t_init(&queue)) != ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    /**************************************
    * Create a concurrent queue of tasks. *
    **************************************/
    for (szi = 0; szi < len; szi++)
    {
        task_desc = malloc(sizeof *task_desc);

        if (task_desc == NULL)
        {
            concurrent_queue_t_destroy(&queue);
            return ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL;
        }

        task_desc->input_element = input[szi];
        task_desc->output_element_address = &output[szi];
        ret = concurrent_queue_t_enqueue(&queue, task_desc);

        if (ret != ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS)
        {
            concurrent_queue_t_destroy(&queue);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    /*****************************
    * Create the worker threads. *
    *****************************/
    threads = malloc(number_of_cores * sizeof(*threads));

    if (threads == NULL)
    {
        concurrent_queue_t_destroy(&queue);
        return ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL;
    }

    wtpa = malloc(number_of_cores * sizeof(*wtpa));

    if (wtpa == NULL)
    {
        free(threads);
        concurrent_queue_t_destroy(&queue);
        return ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL;
    }

    for (szi = 0; szi < number_of_cores; szi++)
    {
        wtpa[szi].concurrent_queue = &queue;
        wtpa[szi].func = func;
        wtpa[szi].return_status = 0;

#ifdef __APPLE__
        ret = pthread_create(&threads[szi],
                             NULL,
                             worker_thread_proc,
                             &wtpa[szi]);
#elif defined(__linux__)
        ret = pthread_create(&threads[szi],
                             NULL,
                             worker_thread_proc,
                             &wtpa[szi]);
#elif defined(_WIN32)
        threads[szi] = CreateThread(NULL,
                                    100000,
                                    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) worker_thread_proc,
                                    (LPVOID) &wtpa[szi],
                                    0,
                                    NULL);
#endif

        if (ret != 0)
        {
            cancel_threads(threads, szi);
            concurrent_queue_t_destroy(&queue);
            return ERROR_FORP_NO_THREAD;
        }

        if (wtpa[szi].return_status != 0)
        {
            cancel_threads(threads, szi + 1);
            concurrent_queue_t_destroy(&queue);
            return ERROR_FORP_NO_SETCANCELTYPE;
        }
    }

    /***********************************************
    * Wait for all the worker threads to complete. *
    ***********************************************/
    for (szi = 0; szi < number_of_cores; szi++)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        if (WaitForSingleObject(threads[szi], INFINITE) != 0 && join_ret == 0)
        {
            join_ret = ERROR_FORP_NO_JOIN;
        }
#else
        join_ret = pthread_join(threads[szi], NULL);

        if (ret != 0 && join_ret == ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS)
        {
            join_ret = ERROR_FORP_NO_JOIN;
        }
#endif
    }

    return join_ret;
}

const char* forp_error(int error_code)
{
    switch (error_code)
    {
        case ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS:
            return "forp succeeded.";

        case ERROR_FORP_NO_ARGS:
            return "Some arguments missing.";

        case ERROR_FORP_NO_JOIN:
            return "Could not join a thread.";

        case ERROR_FORP_CPU_FEOF:
            return "Reached EOF while reading the number of processors.";

        case ERROR_FORP_NO_THREAD:
            return "Could create a thread.";

        case ERROR_FORP_CPU_FERROR:
            return "An error occured while reading the number of processors.";

        case ERROR_FORP_POPEN_FAIL:
            return "Could not execute a program in popen.";

        case ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL:
            return "A call to malloc returned NULL.";

        case ERROR_FORP_SSCANF_FAIL:
            return "sscanf failed.";

        case ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_INIT:
            return "Could not initialize a mutex.";

        case ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_DESTROY:
            return "Could not destroy a mutex.";

        case ERROR_FORP_UNKNOWN_CORES:
            return "Could not determine the number of processors.";

        case ERROR_FORP_NO_SETCANCELTYPE:
            return "setcanceltype failed.";

        default:
            return "Unknown error code.";
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "parallel_for.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <sys/time.h>
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include <sys/time.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif
#include <time.h>

/*********************************
 * Implements a dummy heavy task. *
 *********************************/
static unsigned long long fibonacci(unsigned long long num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        case 0:
            return 0;

        case 1:
            return 1;

        default:
            return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
    }
}

/*******************************
 * The worker thread procedure. *
 *******************************/
static void* fibonacci_func(void* arg)
{
    unsigned long long* pa = (unsigned long long*) arg;
    unsigned long long* result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
    *result = fibonacci(*pa);
    return result;
}

/**************************************
 * Populates randomly the input array. *
 **************************************/
static void populate_input_randomly(void** input_array, size_t len)
{
    unsigned long long* input_datum;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        input_datum = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long));
        *input_datum = 20 + rand() % 21;
        input_array[i] = input_datum;
    }
}

/***************************
 * Prints the output array. *
 ***************************/
static void print_output(void** output, size_t len)
{
    void* raw_datum;
    unsigned long long datum;
    size_t i;
    char* separator = "";
    printf("[");

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%s", separator);
        separator = ", ";
        raw_datum = output[i];
        datum = *((unsigned long long*) raw_datum);
        printf("%llu", datum);
    }

    puts("]");
}

/**************************************************************
 * Returns a current millisecond count. Used for benchmarking. *
 **************************************************************/
static unsigned long long get_milliseconds()
{
#ifdef __APPLE__
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return 1000 * tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
#elif defined(__linux__)
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return 1000 * tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    return (unsigned long long) GetTickCount64();
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif
}

#define N 100

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    void* input[N];
    void* output[N];
    unsigned long long start;
    unsigned long long end;
    size_t i;
    int error_code;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    populate_input_randomly(input, N);

    start = get_milliseconds();
    error_code = forp(input, output, N, fibonacci_func);
    end = get_milliseconds();

    print_output(output, N);
    printf("Parallel for took %llu milliseconds. Error message: %s\n\n",
           end - start,
           forp_error(error_code));

    start = get_milliseconds();

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        output[i] = fibonacci_func(input[i]);
    }

    end = get_milliseconds();
    print_output(output, N);
    printf("Sequential for took %llu milliseconds.\n", end - start);

#ifdef _WIN32
    getchar();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

## Example output, two physical cores, Mac OS X:

> ```
> [28657, 514229, 24157817, 6765, 514229, 832040, 9227465, 121393, 10946, 63245986, 832040, 63245986, 832040, 102334155, 2178309, 514229,
> 832040, 317811, 2178309, 317811, 63245986, 46368, 39088169, 5702887,
> 9227465, 75025, 3524578, 514229, 17711, 196418, 317811, 24157817,
> 39088169, 24157817, 24157817, 832040, 63245986, 46368, 317811, 196418,
> 121393, 196418, 10946, 1346269, 9227465, 121393, 3524578, 514229,
> 46368, 39088169, 9227465, 10946, 832040, 14930352, 3524578, 2178309,
> 514229, 24157817, 3524578, 75025, 63245986, 28657, 10946, 10946,
> 17711, 102334155, 317811, 514229, 196418, 14930352, 1346269, 63245986,
> 75025, 1346269, 24157817, 46368, 196418, 1346269, 9227465, 28657,
> 39088169, 9227465, 121393, 832040, 9227465, 10946, 514229, 6765,
> 9227465, 3524578, 10946, 9227465, 9227465, 317811, 10946, 196418,
> 46368, 6765, 28657, 2178309]
> Parallel for took 7385 milliseconds. Error message: forp succeeded.
>
> [28657, 514229, 24157817, 6765, 514229, 832040, 9227465, 121393, 10946, 63245986, 832040, 63245986, 832040, 102334155, 2178309, 514229,
> 832040, 317811, 2178309, 317811, 63245986, 46368, 39088169, 5702887,
> 9227465, 75025, 3524578, 514229, 17711, 196418, 317811, 24157817,
> 39088169, 24157817, 24157817, 832040, 63245986, 46368, 317811, 196418,
> 121393, 196418, 10946, 1346269, 9227465, 121393, 3524578, 514229,
> 46368, 39088169, 9227465, 10946, 832040, 14930352, 3524578, 2178309,
> 514229, 24157817, 3524578, 75025, 63245986, 28657, 10946, 10946,
> 17711, 102334155, 317811, 514229, 196418, 14930352, 1346269, 63245986,
> 75025, 1346269, 24157817, 46368, 196418, 1346269, 9227465, 28657,
> 39088169, 9227465, 121393, 832040, 9227465, 10946, 514229, 6765,
> 9227465, 3524578, 10946, 9227465, 9227465, 317811, 10946, 196418,
> 46368, 6765, 28657, 2178309]
> Sequential for took 17403 milliseconds.
> ```

## On portability

I was able to compile/run the program without changes on:

1. Visual Studio 2017/Windows 10
2. `gcc` 7.2.0/Ubuntu Linux
3. Xcode 8.3.3/Mac OS X

Comment: `#define POSIX` isn't valid. You want `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE`. (See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_02)

Comment: @Finn, did you mean to comment on vnp's *answer* rather than the *question*?

Comment: WHOOPS. Yes. I misread and assumed that vnp was quoting from coderodde's submission.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- The code for apple and linux cases is identical (except one case). Consider

  ```
  #if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__)
  #define POSIX
  #endif
  ```

  and consolidate the identical blocks under `#ifdef POSIX`. Or consistently do

  ```
  #ifdef __WIN32__
  ....
  #else
  ....
  #endif
  ```

  as you did near the end of `forp`.
- Determining a number of processors by parsing an output of an external command doesn't look right. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150971/3403834) for details.
- All functions except `forp` shall be static. Especially `concurrent_queue_t_enqueue`, which is surely not designed for a public access.
- I don't see why `concurrent_queue_t` is implemented as a linked list. An array of `task_desc` with a mutex-protected cursor seems enough. It is much easier on memory.
- It is advisable (though not mandatory) to avoid `_t` type names. See **B.2.12 Data Types** section of the Posix standard (1003.1, Rationale (Informative)).

Comment: Or just `__unix__`

Comment: @TavianBarnes May work too.

Comment: #define POSIX isn't valid. You want #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE. (See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_02)