# A portable parallel loop construct in C89 - follow-up

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

This is a follow-up question to [A portable parallel loop construct in C89](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185612/a-portable-parallel-loop-construct-in-c89). I have incorporated all the good points made by [vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp). Now my code looks like this:

**parallel_for.h**

```
#ifndef PARALLEL_FOR_H
#define PARALLEL_FOR_H

#include <stdlib.h>

#define ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS 0
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_ARGS 1
#define ERROR_FORP_UNKNOWN_CORES 2
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_INIT 3
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_DESTROY 4
#define ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL 5
#define ERROR_FORP_SSCANF_FAIL 6
#define ERROR_FORP_POPEN_FAIL 7
#define ERROR_FORP_CPU_FEOF 8
#define ERROR_FORP_CPU_FERROR 9
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_THREAD 10
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_SETCANCELTYPE 11
#define ERROR_FORP_NO_JOIN 12

/*******************************************************************************
* Runs a multithreaded for loop over the input array producing the results and *
* storing them in the output array.                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
int forp(void** input,
         void** output,
         size_t len,
         void* (*func)(void*));

/*************************************************************************
* Returns a human-readable description of an error code related to forp. *
*************************************************************************/
const char* forp_error(int error_code);

#endif /* PARALLEL_FOR_H */
```

**parallel_for.c**

```
#include "parallel_for.h"

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__)
#define POSIX
#elif defined(_WIN32)

#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef POSIX
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#else
#include <windows.h>
#endif

/******************************************************************************
* A task descriptor specifying the input element and the address at which the *
* output element should be stored.                                            *
******************************************************************************/
typedef struct task_descriptor {
    void* input_element;
    void** output_element_address;
} task_descriptor;

/************************************************************
* This structure implements a concurrent array-based queue. *
************************************************************/
typedef struct concurrent_queue {

#ifdef POSIX
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;
#endif

    task_descriptor** array;
    size_t begin_index;
    size_t end_index;
    size_t size;
    size_t len;
} concurrent_queue;

/************************************************************
* Initializes the input concurrent queue to an empty state. *
************************************************************/
static int concurrent_queue_init(concurrent_queue* queue, size_t len)
{
    int ret;
    queue->array = malloc(len * sizeof(*queue->array));

    if (queue->array == NULL)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL;
    }

    queue->begin_index = 0;
    queue->end_index = 0;
    queue->size = 0;
    queue->len = len;

#ifdef POSIX

    ret = pthread_mutex_init(&queue->mutex, NULL);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_INIT;
    }

#else

    InitializeCriticalSection(&queue->criticalSection);

#endif

    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
}

/******************************************************
* Appends a task descriptor to the tail of the queue. *
******************************************************/
static void concurrent_queue_enqueue(concurrent_queue* queue,
    task_descriptor* descriptor)
{
    queue->array[queue->end_index] = descriptor;
    queue->end_index++;
    queue->size++;
}

/******************************************************************************
* Removes the head element from the queue. Unlike all other functions related *
* to the queue, this is one is thread-safe.                                   *
******************************************************************************/
static task_descriptor* concurrent_queue_dequeue(concurrent_queue* queue)
{
    task_descriptor* descriptor;

#ifdef POSIX
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->mutex);
#else
    EnterCriticalSection(&queue->criticalSection);
#endif

    if (queue->size > 0)
    {
        descriptor = queue->array[queue->begin_index];
        queue->begin_index++;
        queue->size--;
    }
    else
    {
        descriptor = NULL;
    }

#ifdef POSIX
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->mutex);
#else
    LeaveCriticalSection(&queue->criticalSection);
#endif

    return descriptor;
}

/*****************************************************************************
* Releases all the resources occupied by the queue, or namely, the mutex and *
* the array.                                                                 *
*****************************************************************************/
static int concurrent_queue_destroy(concurrent_queue* queue)
{
    int ret;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < queue->len; i++)
    {
        free(queue->array[i]);
    }

    free(queue->array);

#ifdef POSIX
    ret = pthread_mutex_destroy(&queue->mutex);
    return ret == 0 ? ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS : ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_DESTROY;
#else
    DeleteCriticalSection(&queue->criticalSection);
    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
#endif

}

/*******************************************************
* Returns the number of processors on Mac OS or Linux. *
*******************************************************/
static int get_number_of_processors_apple_linux(size_t* p_number_of_processors)
{
#ifdef POSIX
    *p_number_of_processors = (size_t)sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
#endif

    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
}

/***********************************************
* Returns the number of processors on Windows. *
***********************************************/
static int get_number_of_processors_windows(size_t* p_number_of_processors)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    *p_number_of_processors = (size_t)2 * si.dwNumberOfProcessors;
#endif

    return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
}

/**************************************************************
* A portable function for returning the number of processors. *
**************************************************************/
static int get_number_of_processors(size_t* p_number_of_processors)
{
#ifdef POSIX
    return get_number_of_processors_apple_linux(p_number_of_processors);
#else
    return get_number_of_processors_windows(p_number_of_processors);
#endif
}

/*****************************************************************************
* Specifies the worker thread arguments. Holds the queue and the function to *
* be applied to each queue element.                                          *
*****************************************************************************/
typedef struct worker_thread_proc_args {
    concurrent_queue* queue;
    void* (*func)(void*);
    int return_status;
} worker_thread_proc_args;

/*********************************
* Implements the worker threads. *
*********************************/
static void* worker_thread_proc(void* args)
{
    worker_thread_proc_args* worker_thread_proc_arguments =
        (worker_thread_proc_args*)args;

    concurrent_queue* queue = worker_thread_proc_arguments->queue;
    void* (*func)(void*) = worker_thread_proc_arguments->func;
    task_descriptor* task_desc;
    int ret = 0;

#ifdef POSIX
    ret = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
#endif

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        worker_thread_proc_arguments->return_status = ret;
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        worker_thread_proc_arguments->return_status = 0;
    }

    while ((task_desc = concurrent_queue_dequeue(queue)) != NULL)
    {
        *task_desc->output_element_address = func(task_desc->input_element);
    }

    return NULL;
}

/***************************************
* Cancels all the first 'len' threads. *
***************************************/
#ifdef POSIX
static void cancel_threads(pthread_t* pthreads, size_t len)
#else
static void cancel_threads(HANDLE* threads, size_t len)
#endif
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {

#ifdef POSIX
        pthread_cancel(pthreads[i]);
#else
        TerminateThread(threads[i], 0);
#endif

    }
}

/***********************************************************
* The actual implementation of the parallel for construct. *
***********************************************************/
int forp(void** input, void** output, size_t len, void* (*func)(void*))
{
    size_t number_of_cores;
    size_t szi;
    int ret;
    int join_ret = ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
    concurrent_queue queue;
    task_descriptor* task_desc;
    worker_thread_proc_args* wtpa;

#ifdef POSIX

    pthread_t* threads;

#else

    HANDLE* threads;

#endif

    if (input == NULL || output == NULL || func == NULL)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_NO_ARGS;
    }

    if (len == 0)
    {
        /*****************
        * Nothing to do. *
        *****************/
        return ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS;
    }

    ret = get_number_of_processors(&number_of_cores);

    if (ret != ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    if (number_of_cores == 0)
    {
        return ERROR_FORP_UNKNOWN_CORES;
    }

    if ((ret = concurrent_queue_init(&queue, len)) != ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    /**************************************
    * Create a concurrent queue of tasks. *
    **************************************/
    for (szi = 0; szi < len; szi++)
    {
        task_desc = malloc(sizeof *task_desc);

        if (task_desc == NULL)
        {
            concurrent_queue_destroy(&queue);
            return ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL;
        }

        task_desc->input_element = input[szi];
        task_desc->output_element_address = &output[szi];
        concurrent_queue_enqueue(&queue, task_desc);

        if (ret != ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS)
        {
            concurrent_queue_destroy(&queue);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    /*****************************
    * Create the worker threads. *
    *****************************/
    threads = malloc(number_of_cores * sizeof(*threads));

    if (threads == NULL)
    {
        concurrent_queue_destroy(&queue);
        return ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL;
    }

    wtpa = malloc(number_of_cores * sizeof(*wtpa));

    if (wtpa == NULL)
    {
        free(threads);
        concurrent_queue_destroy(&queue);
        return ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL;
    }

    for (szi = 0; szi < number_of_cores; szi++)
    {
        wtpa[szi].queue = &queue;
        wtpa[szi].func = func;
        wtpa[szi].return_status = 0;

#ifdef POSIX
        ret = pthread_create(&threads[szi],
            NULL,
            worker_thread_proc,
            &wtpa[szi]);
#else
        threads[szi] = CreateThread(NULL,
            100000,
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)worker_thread_proc,
            (LPVOID)&wtpa[szi],
            0,
            NULL);
#endif

        if (ret != 0)
        {
            cancel_threads(threads, szi);
            concurrent_queue_destroy(&queue);
            return ERROR_FORP_NO_THREAD;
        }

        if (wtpa[szi].return_status != 0)
        {
            cancel_threads(threads, szi + 1);
            concurrent_queue_destroy(&queue);
            return ERROR_FORP_NO_SETCANCELTYPE;
        }
    }

    /***********************************************
    * Wait for all the worker threads to complete. *
    ***********************************************/
    for (szi = 0; szi < number_of_cores; szi++)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32

        if (WaitForSingleObject(threads[szi], INFINITE) != 0 && join_ret == 0)
        {
            join_ret = ERROR_FORP_NO_JOIN;
        }
#else
        join_ret = pthread_join(threads[szi], NULL);

        if (ret != 0 && join_ret == ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS)
        {
            join_ret = ERROR_FORP_NO_JOIN;
        }
#endif
    }

    return join_ret;
}

const char* forp_error(int error_code)
{
    switch (error_code)
    {
    case ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS:
        return "forp succeeded.";

    case ERROR_FORP_NO_ARGS:
        return "Some arguments missing.";

    case ERROR_FORP_NO_JOIN:
        return "Could not join a thread.";

    case ERROR_FORP_CPU_FEOF:
        return "Reached EOF while reading the number of processors.";

    case ERROR_FORP_NO_THREAD:
        return "Could create a thread.";

    case ERROR_FORP_CPU_FERROR:
        return "An error occured while reading the number of processors.";

    case ERROR_FORP_POPEN_FAIL:
        return "Could not execute a program in popen.";

    case ERROR_FORP_MALLOC_FAIL:
        return "A call to malloc returned NULL.";

    case ERROR_FORP_SSCANF_FAIL:
        return "sscanf failed.";

    case ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_INIT:
        return "Could not initialize a mutex.";

    case ERROR_FORP_NO_MUTEX_DESTROY:
        return "Could not destroy a mutex.";

    case ERROR_FORP_UNKNOWN_CORES:
        return "Could not determine the number of processors.";

    case ERROR_FORP_NO_SETCANCELTYPE:
        return "setcanceltype failed.";

    default:
        return "Unknown error code.";
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "parallel_for.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__)
#define POSIX
#endif

#if defined(POSIX)
#include <sys/time.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#else
#error "Platform not supported."
#endif

/*********************************
* Implements a dummy heavy task. *
*********************************/
static unsigned long long fibonacci(unsigned long long num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        case 0:
            return 0;

        case 1:
            return 1;

        default:
            return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
    }
}

/*******************************
* The worker thread procedure. *
*******************************/
static void* fibonacci_func(void* arg)
{
    unsigned long long* pa = (unsigned long long*) arg;
    unsigned long long* result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
    *result = fibonacci(*pa);
    return result;
}

/**************************************
* Populates randomly the input array. *
**************************************/
static void populate_input_randomly(void** input_array, size_t len)
{
    unsigned long long* input_datum;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        input_datum = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long));
        *input_datum = 20 + rand() % 21;
        input_array[i] = input_datum;
    }
}

/***************************
* Prints the output array. *
***************************/
static void print_output(void** output, size_t len)
{
    void* raw_datum;
    unsigned long long datum;
    size_t i;
    char* separator = "";
    printf("[");

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%s", separator);
        separator = ", ";
        raw_datum = output[i];
        datum = *((unsigned long long*) raw_datum);
        printf("%llu", datum);
    }

    puts("]");
}

/**************************************************************
* Returns a current millisecond count. Used for benchmarking. *
**************************************************************/
static unsigned long long get_milliseconds()
{
#ifdef POSIX
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return 1000 * tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
#else
    return (unsigned long long) GetTickCount64();
#endif
}

#define N 100

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    void* input[N];
    void* output[N];
    unsigned long long start;
    unsigned long long end;
    size_t i;
    int error_code;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    populate_input_randomly(input, N);

    start = get_milliseconds();
    error_code = forp(input, output, N, fibonacci_func);
    end = get_milliseconds();

    print_output(output, N);
    printf("Parallel for took %llu milliseconds. Error message: %s\n\n",
           end - start,
           forp_error(error_code));

    start = get_milliseconds();

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        output[i] = fibonacci_func(input[i]);
    }

    end = get_milliseconds();
    print_output(output, N);
    printf("Sequential for took %llu milliseconds.\n", end - start);

#ifdef _WIN32
    getchar();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

## Example output, two physical cores, Mac OS X:

> ```
> [28657, 514229, 24157817, 6765, 514229, 832040, 9227465, 121393, 10946, 63245986, 832040, 63245986, 832040, 102334155, 2178309, 514229,
> 832040, 317811, 2178309, 317811, 63245986, 46368, 39088169, 5702887,
> 9227465, 75025, 3524578, 514229, 17711, 196418, 317811, 24157817,
> 39088169, 24157817, 24157817, 832040, 63245986, 46368, 317811, 196418,
> 121393, 196418, 10946, 1346269, 9227465, 121393, 3524578, 514229,
> 46368, 39088169, 9227465, 10946, 832040, 14930352, 3524578, 2178309,
> 514229, 24157817, 3524578, 75025, 63245986, 28657, 10946, 10946,
> 17711, 102334155, 317811, 514229, 196418, 14930352, 1346269, 63245986,
> 75025, 1346269, 24157817, 46368, 196418, 1346269, 9227465, 28657,
> 39088169, 9227465, 121393, 832040, 9227465, 10946, 514229, 6765,
> 9227465, 3524578, 10946, 9227465, 9227465, 317811, 10946, 196418,
> 46368, 6765, 28657, 2178309]
> Parallel for took 7385 milliseconds. Error message: forp succeeded.
>
> [28657, 514229, 24157817, 6765, 514229, 832040, 9227465, 121393, 10946, 63245986, 832040, 63245986, 832040, 102334155, 2178309, 514229,
> 832040, 317811, 2178309, 317811, 63245986, 46368, 39088169, 5702887,
> 9227465, 75025, 3524578, 514229, 17711, 196418, 317811, 24157817,
> 39088169, 24157817, 24157817, 832040, 63245986, 46368, 317811, 196418,
> 121393, 196418, 10946, 1346269, 9227465, 121393, 3524578, 514229,
> 46368, 39088169, 9227465, 10946, 832040, 14930352, 3524578, 2178309,
> 514229, 24157817, 3524578, 75025, 63245986, 28657, 10946, 10946,
> 17711, 102334155, 317811, 514229, 196418, 14930352, 1346269, 63245986,
> 75025, 1346269, 24157817, 46368, 196418, 1346269, 9227465, 28657,
> 39088169, 9227465, 121393, 832040, 9227465, 10946, 514229, 6765,
> 9227465, 3524578, 10946, 9227465, 9227465, 317811, 10946, 196418,
> 46368, 6765, 28657, 2178309]
> Sequential for took 17403 milliseconds.
> ```

## On portability

I was able to compile/run the program without changes on:

1. Visual Studio 2017/Windows 10
2. `gcc` 7.2.0/Ubuntu Linux
3. Xcode 8.3.3/Mac OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall the code looks ok. I haven't tried executing it.

**Design**

- The main concern I have with this code, is that I would avoid using "compiler switches" all over the place. This is unfortunately fairly common practice, but since it makes the code mostly unreadable, it is better to keep different versions for different systems completely separated.

  An alternative design could be to create one internal module `parallel_base.h`/`parallel_base.c` which declares and defines all internal variables and functions shared by all systems. Everything POSIX-related would then be moved to a `parallel_posix.h`/`parallel_posix.c` and everything Windows to `parallel_windows.h`/`parallel_windows.c`. The compiler switches that activates one version or the other are located in the system-specific files, and surround the whole contents of that file. With this design, you'll keep the various system ports separated.

  You can then for example declare a variable with incomplete type in `parallel_base.h`, such as `typedef struct thread_t thread_t;` and then let the different ports implement this struct differently - on POSIX it will contain a `pthread_t` and on Windows a `HANDLE`.

  You'd get function prototypes such as `static void cancel_threads (thread_t* threads, size_t len);`

  (And yeah I am aware that `_t` is reserved identifiers in POSIX, but since it was convention to name types like that long before POSIX was invented, I don't care.)

**Functionality**

- The use of functions like `TerminateThread` is discouraged - these should only be used as some very last resort to bluntly clobber a thread to death instead of letting it cleanly finish by itself.

  So instead, you should have some means to communicate with the thread that you need it to finish, such as an event. The thread (in Windows) could then effectively `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` to check if it is "time to die", and then gracefully finish.
- The Windows version contains various fishy casts such as `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)worker_thread_proc` and `(LPVOID)&wtpa[szi]`. If everything is written with correct types, these casts would not be needed. Possibly they are hiding bugs. This is most likely a side-effect from running this through Visual Studio in C++ mode(?). If C compliance is important, it would be better to test the code in a pure C compiler such as Mingw/gcc.

**Coding style**

- All headers should be included from the h file, not from the c file (of course except for the include of its own corresponding header). This will document the code's dependencies for the user of the code. In addition, the `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` in the .c file seem superfluous.
- Always use function prototypes, even for internal functions. `parallel_for.c` would benefit a lot from a list of all internal function on the top, together with a comment explaining the function's purpose. This would significantly increase the readability of the code as whole.
- `ERROR_FORP_SUCCESS` etc could be written as an enum instead. `forp_err_t` or whatever you'd call it. Return this type from `forp()` instead of `int`. And `forp_error(int error_code)` should also be rewritten accordingly. The switch can be replaced with a table lookup of a `static const char*` array with the enum type as index.
- `parallel_for.h` is missing documentation in comments, explaining the purpose and usage of the API. This should always be included in the source file, even though you may have more detailed documentation elsewhere. In particular, it is very important to document that the thread callback function must be implemented in a thread-safe manner.
- I know that you tagged this C89, but just for future reference, look how much more readable the API can become in standard ISO C:

  ```
  int forp(size_t len
           void*  input[len],
           void*  output[len],
           void*  (*func)(void*));
  ```